# 2Sxc News App View Configuration changes not applied to public view. How can I apply the View Configuration publicly?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have installed 2Sxc version 12.2.1 with News App version 4 on DNN 9.9.1.  I created a /news page and added the news app to the page using the first list view (images on left, descriptions on the right).  Everything works as expected, except when I change the default title on the view from "Demo Configuration", it shows my change while I am logged in. When not logged in, the title reverts back to "Demo Configuration".  What am I missing?

Comment: Turns out it is not just the News App, it is all 2Sxc content.  It works on a clean install of DNN. On my sites, updating content while logged in changes the content, however, when viewed publicly all that is displayed is the Demo Content.

Answer (score 1):

Take a close look at the Status of your View Configuration. What you are describing can happen when the Status is set to Hide. Switch it back to Show / Publish Everything and the demo config will no longer be chosen for the unauthenticated users.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not the issue. It is set to Show.  I did a clean install of DNN and it works correctly, but on the copy of our production sites it behaves as described above. I did check when making change to those settings and saving, it does the postback without error.